# How to handle several input value and make it as one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learn react and I got trouble when I want to submit value. What I want is make them in one object.

```
var React = require("react");

var AddContact = React.createClass({
  onSubmit:function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = this.refs.name.value;
  var phoneNumber = this.refs.phoneNumber.value;
  var update = {};


  if(name.length > 0){
   this.refs.name.value = "";
   update.name = name;
 }else if (phoneNumber.length > 0) {
  this.refs.phoneNumber.value = "";
  update.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
 }else if(name === ""){
  this.refs.name.focus();
 }else{
  this.refs.phoneNumber.focus();
 }

 this.props.onSetContact(update);
 },

 render:function(){
  return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" ref="name" placeholder="Contact Name"/>
      <input type="text" ref="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  )
 }
});

module.exports = AddContact;
```

In this case I want to store value on update variable, but what I get here when I submitted they became different object.

Anyway onSetContact is defined on parent component and it just log the output from form.

my objective is make them as {name:[value],phoneNumber:[value]}

thanks guys

Comment: how does the current object look like?

Comment: @brk the current object look like they not submitted together, like this {name:[value]}, {phoneNumber:[value]}. I need to make them together and store the value to array props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
 if(name.length > 0){
   this.refs.name.value = "";
   update.name = name;
 }else if (phoneNumber.length > 0) {
  this.refs.phoneNumber.value = "";
  update.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
 }else if(name === ""){
  this.refs.name.focus();
 }else{
  this.refs.phoneNumber.focus();
 }
```

it will never go to if #2, if `name` exist...

you need to check `phoneNumber` in another `if` statement, like this:

```
if(name.length > 0){
   this.refs.name.value = "";
   update.name = name;
} else {
  this.refs.name.focus();
}

if (phoneNumber.length > 0) {
  this.refs.phoneNumber.value = "";
  update.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
} else {
  this.refs.phoneNumber.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your conditions n `onSubmit` function, since you are using `if-else`, if one statement is true no other will execute, change them to

```
onSubmit:function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = this.refs.name.value;
  var phoneNumber = this.refs.phoneNumber.value;
  var update = {};

  if(name.length > 0 && phoneNumber.length > 0) {
      this.refs.name.value = "";
      update.name = name; 
      this.refs.phoneNumber.value = "";
      update.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
      this.props.onSetContact(update);
  } else if (name.length == 0){
       this.refs.name.focus();
  }else{
       this.refs.phoneNumber.focus();
  }


 },
```

Apart from this the React docs insist on using Ref callbacks instead of string refs, define them like

```
<div>
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" ref={(ip) => this.name=ip} placeholder="Contact Name"/>
      <input type="text" ref={(ip) => this.phoneNumber=ip} placeholder="Phone Number"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
    </form>
  </div>
```

and use them like

```
   var name = this.name.value;
   var phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber.value
```

Comment: anyway, do you know how to validate form submit if there's empty value? mine not works well. Example, when I only filled name input then submitted it still store the name input which should not store any value because every field must be filled

Comment: Could you accept this as an answer considering it fits your needs